# How to know which request failed for which user in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

My jmx file has 30 requests , 30 users, and response data may very according to the user logged. I am using view result tree as listener, **my question is how to know for which user for which a request failed to get a response from server?**

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options, to provide exact solution we need to know more details.

1. JMeter provides information about thread (virtual user) number as "Thread Name"

   [image: JMeter View Results Tree]
2. You can append the relevant JMeter Variable to the sampler name:

   [image: JMeter Add Variable to Thread Name]

---

N.B. Don't use [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) for anything but tests development and debugging as it is very resource intensive, when it comes to load test execution it will consume lots of the RAM and it may ruin your test. [Run you test in command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) and use listeners to analyse the results file **after** test completion. More information on JMeter tuning for the maximum performance: [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)